# Populating an Android ListView with data from an ArrayList is setting each item to be the same as the first

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-internal-storage

I'm working with the android studio and trying to populate a ListView with data, which is stored in files on the devices internal storage. I am able to create a list with the exact number of item as there are files but they should all be displaying different information. At the moment, they are all displaying that same data as the first item in the ArrayList.

Here is the code:

```
 ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int counter = 0;

        int fileNameNumber = 1;

        filename = "newAssessment(" + fileNameNumber + ").json";

        internalFile = new File(directory, filename);

        JSONObject jsonObject;

        while (internalFile.exists()) {

            files.add(counter, internalFile);

            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(internalFile);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String strLine;

                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    myData = myData + strLine;
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(myData);

                    String assessmentDate = jsonObject.getString("assessmentDate");
                    String orchard = jsonObject.getString("orchard");

                    data.add(counter, assessmentDate + " : " + orchard);
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                counter++;
                fileNameNumber++;


            filename = "newAssessment(" + fileNameNumber + ").json";

            internalFile = new File(directory, filename);
        }

        LVAssessments.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
```

I can confirm that different data is being stored. Changing the item which comes first is the array changes all the items.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: where have you been initialized **data**?

Comment: It is a class variable `private List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Declare it in your method

Comment: @KishuDroid Initializing inside of while loop is not a good idea. If we try to initialize like that then only last data will be added all the others not going to add because every time List will reset

Comment: @Amsheer: Yepp I got your point and that's why I commented to initialize in Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not initialize myData in external while loop. So initialize your myData in external while loop.

```
while (internalFile.exists()) {

            files.add(counter, internalFile);

            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(internalFile);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String strLine;

                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    myData = myData + strLine;
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(myData);

                    String assessmentDate = jsonObject.getString("assessmentDate");
                    String orchard = jsonObject.getString("orchard");

                    data.add(counter, assessmentDate + " : " + orchard);
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                counter++;
                fileNameNumber++;
                myData = "";


            filename = "newAssessment(" + fileNameNumber + ").json";

            internalFile = new File(directory, filename);
        }

        LVAssessments.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                myData = myData + strLine;
            }
```

myData still has the older data when the while loop repeats again. You need to initialize myData to a new string before the above while loop repeats again.

```
myData = "";
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                myData = myData + strLine;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use for loop to get all the data from the json object and add them into myData

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm finding it hard to invision what you mean, thanks.